# Waterfall chart with JavaFX

Tags: java, d3.js, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to plot [waterfall charts](http://bl.ocks.org/rsloan/7123450) with JavaFX? If there is no built in functionality, can we use d3.js library with JavaFX?

Comment: I know no built-in functionality to display waterfall charts. You could try to embed [jFreeChart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartWaterfallChartDemo.htm) as swing component, or you can give a try for `d3.js` in a JavaFX `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks. I think d3.js + JavaFX WebView is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could fairly easily implement this yourself using a stacked bar chart with two series:

- make the first series transparent.
- the value of the first series is the sum of the values added.
- the value of the second series is the actual value you're adding
- add an additional value with the sum of all the values

So displaying data of **10**,**15**,**20**,**25**

Would add: {0,**10**},{10,**15**},{25,**20**},{45,**25**},{0,70}